# Is there a way to setup ProxyPass in httpd conf for node server

Tags: node.js, apache, vue.js, httpd.conf, mod-proxy

I run my Apache httpd server which serves web services on port 80. At the same time, node.js server which works with Vue js runs on port 8080.

In order to make this multi port management, I've mentioned proxy pass in httpd conf as shown below.

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_proxy_http.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyPass /node http://localhost:8080/node/
        ProxyPassReverse /node http://localhost:8080/node/
</VirtualHost>
```

Below shown is the error after setting the above proxy settings.
The mentioned app.js is available as http://localhost:8080/app.js

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also solve this problem with CORS settings in Apache conf:

  # remember to replace /var/www with your directory root
  <Directory /var/www>
    # some other apache code here, if any
    # replace the url to the one you wanted
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:8080"
    # some other apache code here, if any
  </Directory>
```